# Leaked GCP API Keys - Your app contains exposed Google Cloud Platform (GCP) API keys

Tags: android, react-native, google-cloud-platform, android-security

I have a react-native app that is already published to Play Store. In the last update, I face to this error and in description google says com.--.MainApplication.onCreate

I have an auto generated api key by firebase that I passed it into a third-party library method in onCreate. I restrict this api key for my app with package name and SHA-1 in GCP Pannel and also use api restriction for this API Key.

Even I try to set this API-Key in string resources and get it from there in onCreate method.

But continuously I see this erorr in my developer panel and finally my app rejected.

Answer (score 0):

You should regenerate a new key, it sounds like the current one has leaked somewhere.

Comment: I don't think so